# aggregation give result of 0 although no data exists

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Having following sql with a join:

```
SELECT sum(r) AS amount
FROM rep.stats
JOIN rep.valdata
    ON rep.valdata.id = rep.stats.data_id
WHERE rep.valdata.custid = 3657 AND
      rep.stats.sdatetime LIKE '2014-09-29%'
```

Problem, my ResultSet gives me one row as result with the value of 0 although no data available. I expect no resultSet. Whats wrong? Is it, because sum(r) return a 0 as default?

This brings me in trouble cause also a 0 value is a value and will be displayed.

Comment: Where is `r` being defined?

Comment: The sum is 0. Nothing wrong at all.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: r is defined in stats table.

Comment: To detect no rows case count rows. `having count(*) >0` for example.

Comment: the SUM of no-results is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.  It is an aggregation query because you have an aggregation function (`SUM()`) in the `select` clause.

An aggregation query with no `group by` treats all the rows as the group -- and all means *all*, including *none*.  So, such a query *always* returns exactly one row which summarizes all rows.

That said, the query should not be returning a value of `0`.  It should be returning a single row with a value of `NULL`.

If you want no row, then add a `group by`:

```
SELECT sum(r) AS amount
FROM rep.stats s JOIN
     rep.valdata v
      ON v.id = s.data_id
WHERE v.custid = 3657 AND
      s.sdatetime >= '2014-09-29' AND
      s.sdatetime < '2015-09-30'
GROUP BY v.custid;
```

Notes:

- The aggregation query now has a `GROUP BY`.  This will return one row per *group*, and if there are no groups, no rows will be returned.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Don't use `LIKE` with date/time values.  This requires converting the date/time to a string, which can depend on internationalization settings.  Plus, it prevents the use of indexes.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you very much, you saved my day. It works nicely and as expected. And thank you also for the hint for datetime issues.